# iPhone and iPad not detected after update appcelerator studio

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio

My iPhone and iPad not detected after update appcelerator studio  (Appcelerator Studio, build: 4.4.0.201511241829). 
Android device detected easily but ios device not detected after refresh devices not worked.
Can some one help me. what have to do.

Comment: Does Xcode detect your device? If you plugin the device, open Xcode and navigate to the devices window does it show up there?

Comment: My device detected in Xcode but from appcelerator it is not sowing up or detected.

Comment: If you use the CLI and run `appc ti info -t ios` does it show there? Or any errors?

Comment: This error appear ==========|[ERROR] Failed to run command "info"
[ERROR] Error: Cannot find module '/Users/debapam/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.0.2.GA/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/bindin
g/node-v47-darwin-x64/node_sqlite3.node'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)

Comment: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/debapam/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.0.2.GA/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3.js:4:1
5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:397:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:404:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12) at Module.require (module.js:353:17)

Comment: Could it be that you've upgraded/switched NodeJS versions? This requires NPM packages to be rebuild. You can force the 5.0.2.GA SDK you are using to be reinstalled via `appc ti sdk install -f 5.0.2.GA`

Comment: In other words, do not update appcelerator ever else it will breakdown everything. Its Highly unstable to update.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me, I had to do the following steps to get it working:

1. Uninstalled Appcelerator Studio
2. Downloaded the latest iOS SDK from Apple's dev portal.
3. Installed latest iOS SDK
4. Downloaded and installed fresh Appcelerator Studio

Comment: can you conform me one thinks iOS SDK means latest XCODE Version 7.2.   but my appcelerator project worked fine in ios simulator but not detected in device.  Is there right process to do so. why this problem appear can you told me?